# The committee ON / FOR

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

I have seen sentences with both prepositions (*The committee on* & *The committee for*)

E.g. Consider below written sentences

> The committee **on** criminal justice reforms recommended a threefold strategy to arrest the drift and to prevent total disaster.
>
> The committee **for** criminal justice reforms recommended a threefold strategy to arrest the drift and to prevent total disaster.

Are they both grammatically correct? If yes is there any difference in meaning of these two sentences?

Say if this question is asked in exam as MCQ fill up question with ON and FOR as  options then which one will be the *best* answer?

If their usage varies in American and British English then please reply considering later one.

Comment: [Google Ngrams suggests they're almost equally likely.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=committee+on%2Ccommittee+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommittee%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommittee%20for%3B%2Cc0)  Although we have to consider the context - if the sentence is "We created a committee ___ the purpose of..." obviously only *for* is going to be likely there.  Ngrams is a crude tool.

Comment: Both the prepositions are correct.  "on" is a little more common.

Answer (score 2):

> committee **on** *something*
>   committee **for** *something*

basically have the same meaning. meaning a committee concerned with the subject of *something*.

I believe committee **on** is used more by BrE since **for** might be understood as the committee is advocating (being for/against) the *something*.